# Why am I getting this error with my class date code?

Tags: c#

For this class, I was trying to display a date in 3 different formats.
mm-dd-yyyy, yyyy-mm-dd, and month dd, yyyy

I keep getting the error "Cannot convert from string to int" when i try to run my program. However, i didn't use string purposely in any of my methods. What am i doing wrong?

```
using System;

public class Date
{
    private int month;
    private int date;
    private int year; 
    private int parameter;

    public int getmonth()
    {
        return month;
    }
    public void setmonth(int m)
    { 
        month = m;
    }
    public int getdate()
    {
        return date;
    }
    public void setdate(int d)
    {
        date = d;
    }
    public int getyear()
    {
        return year;
    }
    public void setyear(int y)
    {
        year = y;
    }
    public int getparameter()
    {
        return parameter;
    }
    public void setparameter(int p)
    {
        parameter = p;
        if (p <= 3)
        {
            if (p == 1)
            {
                setmonth("1");
                setdate(22);
                setyear(2015);
            }
            else if (p == 2)
            {
                setyear(2015);
                setmonth("2");
                setdate(20);
            }
            else if (p == 3)
            {
                setmonth("March");
                setdate(10);
                setyear(2015);
            }
        }
    }

}

class DateTest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Date Dave = new Date (1);
        Console.WriteLine("The Date is {0}", Dave.getparameter());
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: `setmonth` takes an integer as input and you are sending a String here --> `setmonth("1");`, here --> `setmonth("2");` and here --> `setmonth("March");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using:

```
setmonth("1");
// ...
setmonth("2");
// ...
setmonth("March");
```

And signature of setmonth is

```
public void setmonth(int m)
{ 
    month = m;
}
```

You can't implicitly convert string to int. Use `setmonth(int.Parse("1"))` etc. Or call it with int value instead of string. Or to combine both, you can overload the methods:

```
public void setmonth(int m)
{ 
    month = m;
}

public void setmonth(string m)
{ 
    month = int.Parse(m);
}
```

Using this you should be able to pass either an int or a string and it will work both times.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string to a method that takes an int on this line:

```
setmonth("1");
```

You defined `setmonth` to take an int:

```
public void setmonth(int m)
```

You could change the `setmonth` call to

```
setmonth(1);
```

And similarly for the other `setmonth` calls.